# I have added a receive boot completed permission on my manifest file but still my app is not receiving boot completed event

Tags: c#, android, maui

Hi Everyone I would like to start a foreground service on boot complete on android. I have added the below permissions and actions in my android manifest but still the app foreground service that displays a notification does not work, what could I have done
wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
 <application android:name="com.companyname.bgapp.app" android:debuggable="true" 
   android:enabled="true" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/mindicon">
 <receiver android:name="com.companyname.bgapp.app.NotifyReceive" android:enabled="true" 
  android:exported="true">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />
 </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Below is the broadcast receiver

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.companyname.bgapp.app.NotifyReceive", Exported = true, 
Enabled = true, DirectBootAware = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] {  Intent.ActionReboot,
    Intent.ActionBootCompleted
    ,Intent.ActionScreenOn
,Intent.ActionUserPresent
```

,Intent.ActionLockedBootCompleted})]
public class NotifyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

```
            Toast.MakeText(context, "background app restarting...",
             ToastLength.Short).Show();
             var serviceIntent = new Intent(context,
                 typeof(NotifyService));
            serviceIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ResetTaskIfNeeded);
            serviceIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
            serviceIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            ContextCompat.StartForegroundService(context,
              serviceIntent);
           
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `Toast`. Replace it with some logging. Is your problem that the receiver is not getting control, or that you cannot start the foreground service from the receiver?

Comment: I don't see any activity in your manifest? You need it to launch your app at least once to be able to receive implicit system broadcasts.

Comment: @Pawel, thank you so much   l have launched it many times. But still its not working. Which activity, where should l add it? And why yhpuld l add it for a foreground service?

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you for your response, but if l add logging where wld l retrive it it dince lm debugging on a local device ie my phone

Comment: @CommonsWare, l can start the service from a screen on event but for some strange reason it doesnt start on boot completed

Comment: "l add logging where wld l retrive it" -- [use Logcat](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html).